# Looking for an alternative for rlwrap to use rman and sqlplus Oracle tools more user friendly

Tags: go, readline

In our environment it is not possible to install realine and rlwrap tools which make our life easier to use Oracle CLI tools like rman and sqlplus.
I found a promising project "github.com/chzyer/readline". I am looking for an example of how to communicate this library with rman tool. Something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os/exec"

    "github.com/chzyer/readline"
)

func main() {
    // Launch RMAN in interactive mode
    rmanCmd := exec.Command("rman", "target", "/")
    rmanStdin, err := rmanCmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rmanStdout, err := rmanCmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rmanStderr, err := rmanCmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    // Merge stdout and stderr pipes
    multiReader := io.MultiReader(rmanStdout, rmanStderr)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(multiReader)
    if err := rmanCmd.Start(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create a new readline instance
    rl, err := readline.NewEx(&readline.Config{
        Prompt:            "RMAN> ",
        HistoryFile:       "/tmp/readline.tmp",
        HistorySearchFold: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rl.Close()
    rl.CaptureExitSignal()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Loop over readline commands until user enters "quit"
    for {
        // Read a line of input from the user
        line, err := rl.Readline()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error:", err)
            break
        }

        // Write the command to the RMAN process
        fmt.Fprintln(rmanStdin, line)

        // Read the output from the RMAN process
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }

        if line == "quit" {
            break
        }
    }

    // Wait for the RMAN process to exit
    if err := rmanCmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not working properly, I don't get back the prompt. So any suggestion or advice is welcome on how to use their library.

Comment: Why not use Oracle's sqlCL or SQL Developer?  Or Oracle's VS Code plugin?

Comment: If you change your mindset and learn Oracle RMAN syntax, I think you will addict into using RMAN command line interface! RMAN is so powerful and adorable! :))